# Word 2010 VBA make a table and text disappear

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a word document and made a command button that is suppose to hide a table. Now when I first set it, I thought I got it working I got it all styled and titled and when I clicked the button the table would disappear.
Then I saved it and closed the document but when I opened up the document I saw that the only thing that was hidden was the words inside the table, the table lines are not hidden and when I toggle the button the only thing hiding is the text.

Is there something I am doing wrong ? Here is the code in VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ThisDocument.Styles("HideText").Font.Hidden = Not ThisDocument.Styles("HideText").Font.Hidden 
End Sub
```

I just want the button to toggle the text and the Table to hide every time it the button is pressed and when the document is open and closed.

Update may be on to something the table has its own style as well. should I be targeting that as well as the text within the style ? is that what is happening ?

Update #2

I was able to now hide and unhide the section of the table I wanted but it doesn't bring up the lines after I make the table visible. So is there a way to get the table grid to show up with the click of the button?

here is what I have so far.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisDocument.Styles("HideText").Font.Hidden = Not ThisDocument.Styles("HideText").Font.Hidden
    'Table Grid
    Dim s As Style
    Dim An As Integer
    An = 0

    If An = 0 Then
    For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
            If s.Type = wdStyleTypeTable Then
                If s.NameLocal = "Table Grid" Then
                    Debug.Print (s.NameLocal)
                    s.Visibility = False
                    s.UnhideWhenUsed = False
                    Call s.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next
    An = 1
    End If

    If An = 1 Then
    For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
            If s.Type = wdStyleTypeTable Then
                If s.NameLocal = "Table Grid" Then
                    Debug.Print (s.NameLocal)
                    s.Visibility = True
                    s.UnhideWhenUsed = True
                    Call s.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next
    An = 0
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this by hiding the font of the table (as below) rather than attempting to hide a specific font style which you're using within the table.

You could try something along the lines of:

```
Public sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Font
        .Hidden = Not .Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That just ended up deleting almost the whole document button and all. how do I tell what table to target ?

Comment: is there a way I can hide borders ?

Comment: You can probably approach selecting a specific table in many ways, however, if you right click the table, click the "alt text" tab and give the table a title you can then reference the title within the code.

Therefore, you could do something like this:

`Public Sub commandButton1_Click()
For Each tTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
  If tTable.Title = "TB" Then
    tTable.Borders.Enable = Not tTable.Borders.Enable
    Exit For
  End If
Next
End Sub`

This will remove the border from the table.

Comment: is there a method I can use with the title and still have your hidden statement for the table just for that table ?